# Creating dynamic temp table from dynamic Buffer

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

Here is my issue:

```
CREATE QUERY hQuery.
    hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(hBuffer).
    hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("/*my conditions*/").
    hQuery:QUERY-OPEN().
```

hBuffer is my buffer handle.

I want to create a temp-table from this hBuffer.How?Pls help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a temp table using dynamic query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357754/how-to-create-a-temp-table-using-dynamic-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "CREATE TEMP-TABLE statement" in on-line help. An example is shown and i believe you can just replace the static table buffers with your dynamic buffer handle....

```
CREATE TEMP-TABLE tth.
tth:CREATE-LIKE(hBuffer).
tth:TEMP-TABLE-PREPARE("MyTT").
ttbh = tth:DEFAULT-BUFFER-HANDLE.

/* populate */
ttbh:BUFFER-CREATE.
ttbh:BUFFER-COPY(hBuffer).
```